# Print data to a spreadsheet instead of the immediate window

Tags: excel, vba, list, parsing, web

I have a while loop that scraps the web for data. Within that while statement there is an If statement. When the condition for the if statement is true it prints to my immediate window. I need it to print the first item of the list to A1, the second to A2 and so on and so forth until the subroutine is complete. Can anyone help me with this? I feel like this should be rather easy to accomplish, however I felt that way 3 hours ago when I began searching for the solution to this problem.

This is the current code That contains the if statement.

```
If Left(var.innerText, 4) = "I123" Then
Newvar = Mid(var.outerHTML, 44, 12)
Range("A1:A200").Value = Newvar
End If
```

This is an example of the output that is displayed in the immediate window when I execute the code.

I12307025601

I12307025701

I12307025801

I12307025901

I12307026001

I cannot find a way to have it print this list starting on A1 and then go to A2 and so on.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer added by @Black cat then please accept it by clicking in the grey check mark next to it, this keeps the focus on the outstanding questions and helps future readers understand the answer was OK for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of your Sub place a declaration

```
Dim rowcounter as Long
```

```
If Left(var.innerText, 4) = "I123" Then
rowcounter = rowcounter + 1            'added
Newvar = Mid(var.outerHTML, 44, 12)
Range("A" & rowcounter).Value = Newvar  'edited
End If
```

This place the values to the ActiveSheet or the sheet where the code is placed in the sheet's code pane.

If you want a specific Sheet to use declare it in this way

```
Worksheets("the_sheet_name").Range("A" & rowcounter).Value = Newvar
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you so much. That was driving me crazy!!